# React api fetch

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, fetch

i'm new with react and api. i try to get an api with fetch from mongodb.
the console.log is ok, but i bug to render it.

```
import React from 'react';

class Api extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const apiUrl = 'https://us-east-1.aws.webhooks.mongodb-realm.com/api/client/v2.0/app/cv-xfzvw/service/cv/incoming_webhook/api?secret=cv';
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log('This is your data', data));
  }
  render() {
    return {data};
  }
}
export default Api;
```

Does anyone know how how to return body ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: 1. Create a local state of the component. 2. In the `componentDidMount`, when the data is available in the 2nd `then()` method's callback function, update the state. 3. Render the data from the state in the `render()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define local status in your class component first, then use setState to set the value. When state value changed, the component will be re-rendered, the render() will refresh the value on browser.

try this:

```js
import React from "react";

class Api extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const that = this;
    const apiUrl =
      "https://us-east-1.aws.webhooks.mongodb-realm.com/api/client/v2.0/app/cv-xfzvw/service/cv/incoming_webhook/api?secret=cv";
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        that.setState({ data: JSON.stringify(json) });
      });
  }
  render() {
    return <div>my data: {this.state.data}</div>;
  }
}
export default Api;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on the topic, but as far as I can see from render you need to return a component.
Additionally, you might first want to save your api response data to state, and then use it.
From the code above, "data" does not have any visibility in your render method.